# Youcompleteme: shortcut key to format selection

Tags: vimrc, key-bindings, plugin-you-complete-me

According to [this documentation](https://github.com/ycm-core/YouCompleteMe)

`:'<,'>YcmCompleter Format`

will format the selected text. I am struggling to map this to shortcut key `<S-F2>`.

I have tried all of the following after having visually line selected the lines:

Attempt1: `vmap <S-F2> :YcmCompleter Format<CR>`

Attempt2: `nmap <S-F2> :YcmCompleter Format<CR>`

Attempt3:

```
function! YCMFormat()
    silent execute ":'<,'>YcmCompleter Format"
endfunction
vnoremap <S-F2> :call YCMFormat()<CR>
```

Attempt4:

```
function! YCMFormat()
    silent execute ":'<,'>YcmCompleter Format"
endfunction
nnoremap <S-F2> :call YCMFormat()<CR>
```

None of the above work. After hitting these keys, the focus shifts to the bottom command line which displays:

```
Entering Ex mode.  Type "visual" to go to Normal mode.
:
```

Is there a way to correctly assign `<S-F2>` to format the visually selected lines?

Comment: Possibly your terminal and vim pair do not work with that key combo—try a regular key first and see if the mapping works

Comment: @D.BenKnoble Thank you. You were absolutely correct. `vmap <Leader>ft :YcmCompleter Format<CR>` works like a charm !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, `<S-F2>` may not work in some terminals or with some vims. Using another key solves the issue of binding it correctly: I would use something like

```
vnoremap <leader>f :YcmCompleter Format<CR>
```

But it might also be nice to set `formatexpr` or `indentexpr` instead.